# Docker RUN groupadd && useradd directives have no effect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I've built my Docker nginx 'base' image with a Dockerfile whose fragment is below:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Me <me.net>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
..
```

This image was then linked with a database container and data volume. Later, I wanted to add a user to the container so that I could run applications as this user so I added 'RUN groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33' directive to the Dockerfile so that my Dockerfile would look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Me <me.net>

RUN groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
..
```

Then I rebuit an image with `docker build -rm .`, and then run the whole stack again with `docker-compose up` (I have the stack configured in docker-compose.yml).

Unfortunately, although the `RUN groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33` step did not error out, when I entered the shell of the running nginx container, `luqo33` user or `luqo33` group were not there. I then executed the same commands (`groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33`) from the shell, and the group and user were added as expected.

Why wouldn't `RUN groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33` in Dockerfile add the user and the group to the new container upon rebuilding? I also tried `docker build --no-cache .` with the same effect (or lack of it). What am I missing here?

Comment: No idea, but I can tell you I have this in a Dockerfile and I use the user gg `RUN useradd -d /home/gg -m -s /bin/bash gg
RUN echo gg:gg | chpasswd
RUN echo 'gg ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/gg
RUN chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/gg
USER gg
`

Comment: I find it hard to believe this doesn't work. I think you're just running with an old image. In `docker build` you will need to tag it with the image name used docker-compose, or use docker-compose to rebuild the image.

Comment: @luqo33 Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

to make sure your build command isn't making use of any cached layer, use the [`--no-cache`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#build) option.

```
docker build --no-cache .
```

If you want the same with docker-compose:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Also since you are using *docker-compose* to start the container, make sure to run `docker-compose rm` or else docker-compose will reuse previously built images.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer:

As you noted the command didn't error and completed successfully. So the question to be asked then is not whether the build completed successfully, but rather, "*where does my new changes live?*". Since you tried the `docker build --no-cache` switch, you've excluded caching as a possible cause of the fault so I won't review that.

When you executed the `docker build` command, it created a **NEW** but **UNTAGGED** image. You must replace the original image you cut the new changed image from in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

You can either specify the new image with your changes in your `docker-compose.yml` for the `image:` directive either by the new ID (printed in the output of the command), or you can execute the `docker build` command with the `-t` switch to give it a memorable name and specify this in the `docker-compose.yml'

After which, when you now raise the container up you'll see your changes.

## Longer Answer:

A simple example:

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest
USER root
RUN groupadd -r docker -g 998 && usermod -aG docker zabbix
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 zabbix-agent:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest

<SNIP>
```

We execute the `docker build` command:

```
docker build --no-cache . -f Dockerfile-ZabbixAgent2
```

Which produces the following output. Please remark the final line which prints the new image id `648beab6b981`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  64.51kB
Step 1/3 : FROM zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest
ubuntu-6.0-latest: Pulling from zabbix/zabbix-agent2
5a7855fb0d7a: Pull complete 
f9a859e41b71: Pull complete 
f7ad9919c519: Pull complete 
20ea4fedbcbd: Pull complete 
f3bd36582888: Pull complete 
bb43875752a1: Pull complete 
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete 
731b7384d85e: Pull complete 
Digest: 
sha256:429d25c005ffc8a81313daf117eaa9e331bba7073cd4f96854a8787ee1f90a93
Status: Downloaded newer image for zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest
 ---> 3582bfb78810
Step 2/3 : USER root
 ---> Running in a3bb277b6c6c
Removing intermediate container a3bb277b6c6c
 ---> 81ed7850f671
Step 3/3 : RUN groupadd -r docker -g 998 && usermod -aG docker zabbix
 ---> Running in 84acc1494ecc
Removing intermediate container 84acc1494ecc
 ---> 648beab6b981
Successfully built 648beab6b981
```

The above output reveals both that the changes were successful ("***Step 3/3***" and that Image ID `648beab6b981` was produced from our changes. If we now list our images, we'll see `648beab6b981`, but as an untagged image:

```
docker image ls

REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>                 <none>              648beab6b981   39 seconds ago   105MB
zabbix/zabbix-agent2   ubuntu-6.0-latest   3582bfb78810   2 weeks ago      105MB
```

We can validate that our changes had effect. In `docker-compose.yml`, we change the image name by commenting-out the name of the base image and appending below it the image ID of our new changed image:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 zabbix-agent:
  #image: zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest
   image: 648beab6b981
<SNIP>
```

We raise the container up:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --compatibility --profile all up -d
```

(**NOTE**: `--compatibility --profile all up` is used because I'm working with a version 3 `docker-compose.yml` file)

Then we check to see if our new group membership is correct by logging into the container by its' container ID (derived from `docker ps`):

```
docker exec -it 71f475b28165 bash
```

Now we use `id` to check the zabbix user's group memberships:

```
root@71f475b28165:/var/lib/zabbix# id zabbix
uid=1997(zabbix) gid=1995(zabbix) groups=1995(zabbix),0(root),998(docker)
```

Yes, our changes are all there. But we could only see them when we changed the image name in `docker-compose.yml` to the **NEW** image we cut from the `docker build` command by specifying its' id as we lacked a tag.

### Specifying the New (changed) Image by TAG:

Using the id is ugly and can create confusion in the future. So we want a tag image ideally.

However, a new tag CANNOT be specified in a `docker-compose.yml` file. This must be done in the `docker build` command with the `-t` switch and specifying the new name.

Below I just appended `-dockerfix` at the end of the original name so I'll know what the changed image is based upon when I see it in the future in an `docker image ls`:

```
docker build -t zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest-dockerfix --no-cache . -f Dockerfile-ZabbixAgent2
```

The last line of the output of the `docker build` command will print:

```
`Successfully tagged zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest-dockerfix`
```

We now edit the `image` directive in our `docker-compose.yml` file to replace the base image name with the new tagged image we just cut, "***zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest-dockerfix***".

When we next execute:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --compatibility --profile all up -d
```

The new CHANGED image with our changes will rise-up.