# Docker image - add user to group

Tags: image, docker, containers

I have an custom docker image, already builded. There is no Dockerfile available. Inside container, instead of root, an custom user, let's say *test*, is available. This user is attached to group *test*. This is default user for container.

I try to build my own image using described above base image, and add user *test* also to group *workers*. How to do this?

Using known commands (useradd, addgroup, usermod) known by me, is not helpful.
After *docker exec* inside container, command *id* returns me only one group (*test*).

Also access to files mounted to container with permissions *anotheruser:workers* / 770 is not possible.

Is there a chance to do this?

Comment: Can you provide your custom image's Dockerfile, and the exact commands you're running?  "Log in" has a specific Linux meaning that never happens in Docker; how are you accessing the container, and what do you expect to normally run there?  Have you looked at options like the [`docker run --group-add`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups) option that don't require modifying the image?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, thank you for response. Login is not the best description; I am using docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash. The main process inside container requires to be run from this specific user.

Answer (score 2):

## Process:

A brief outline of the process for modifying your current image to incorporate changes into a new image is as follows:

1. Create a `Dockerfile` with the current image and your changes to modify it
2. Execute the `docker build` command to cut a new image from the Dockerfile
3. Update your `docker-compose.yml` file's `image:` directive with the new image's name ("tag")

## A Simple Worked Example:

Create a `Dockerfile` in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
FROM zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest
USER root
RUN groupadd -r docker -g 998 && usermod -aG docker zabbix
```

The original `docker-compose.yml` file containing the image you're currently using:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 zabbix-agent:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest

<SNIP>
```

Execute the `docker build` command with the `-t` switch to give it a memorable name:

```
docker build -t zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest-dockerfix --no-cache . -f Dockerfile-ZabbixAgent2
```

Then we change the original image's name in our `docker-compose.yml` file to the tag of the new image based on the changes in the Dockercompose file.

Comment-out the name of the base image and append the new tag below it:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 zabbix-agent:
  #image: zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest
   image: zabbix/zabbix-agent2:ubuntu-6.0-latest-dockerfix
<SNIP>
```

When you raise the container up now, you'll see the new changes to your users & groups from the `RUN` command in the Dockerfile.

A **VERY** detailed example can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71736885/10009950) if you need further context.

Hope this helps-